# plitting rows in groupby to create columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm having some trouble with groupby.
I've tried a couple of different things like pivot_table (but I'm also struggling with that too).

this is my current outcome from the code

```
df[['home_team_name','away_team_name','match_id','type_name','possession_team_name']].groupby(['home_team_name','away_team_name','possession_team_name','match_id']).agg({'type_name':'count'}).reset_index()
```

[image: currrent outcome]

0:1 index are the same game, 2:3 index are the same game so on and so forth. What I'm trying to do is take every 2nd row, and result something that would have the columns of

```
home_team_name, away_team_name,possession_team_name,match_id,home_team_type_name, away_team_type_name
Angel City      Chicago Red Stars  Chicago Red Stars  3829340  632 744
```

Comment: post a few lines of your dataframe and the expected result. This way you will be answered much faster.

Comment: thanks, I forgot to say I had the answer. I ended up just making DF's out of odd and even rows and merging.

Comment: If you haven't solved the problem yet. Just copy some of your original dataframe here so can keep it for yourself and work with it. Show the expected result.